# see numbers in regex with out special character

Tags: python, regex, numbers, digits

I just want to see numbers with out this special character "," comma with regex in python,  number are like this:

`143,000 is price
126,479,000 hours you worked`

and i just want to see **full match** like this:

`143000
126479000`

Comment: Can you provide us with what you have implemented so far ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
import re


my_text = '1,222,222 test'

my_out = re.search(r'[0-9|,]{1,}',my_text).group().replace(',','')

print(my_out)
```